# Correct Use of log4j

Tags: log4j

I'm a student and we have to do a software project. My current task is to look after exception logging.

I'm using log4j and this is my example code:

```
public void function(){
try {
  something();
}
catch (Exception e){
  logger.error("Error: " + e + " Method: " + e.getStackTrace()[0].getMethodName() + ".");
}
}
```

I would add that "logger.xxx" in every catch-block. I wonder if there is any way to do it "better". Or is my chosen approach the correct choice?

I'm not used to write in english, so I hope you can understand, what I'm asking for :)

Answer (score 1):

Adding a logger.error statement into your catch blocks is a good practice.  The Logger class does include a method to pass the actual Exception too.  This way, the stack trace can be logged also, which can be very helpful in researching the cause of the error.

Here's an example:

```
try {
    something();
}
catch (Exception e) {
    logger.error("Error caught! Looks like something went wrong.", e);
}
```